# ChartJS change axis label

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, axis

I want to change the axis label on my chart.

I need to move the axis label from the center to the right (as well as move it from red area to the blue area)

It currently looks like this:
[image]

```js
myChart  = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {        
    type: 'bubble',     
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Ёмкость рынка и количество сделок'
      }, scales: {
        yAxes: [{ 
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: "Ёмкость, млн. BYN"
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{             
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,             
            labelString: "Ёмкость, тыс. кв. м",
            
          }
        }]
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: check out: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html It looks like you can set scale properties, which you could use to move the label to the right

Comment: @Maxion did you find a solution?